# How to play popup sound while displaying popup window

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

I'm displaying pop up window using the below code:

```
var left = (screen.width/2)-(400/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(400/2);
targetWin2 = window.open ('', 'popup', 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=400, height=10,     top='+top+', left='+left);
```

It works; but how to play pop up sound while displaying this window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with something like this:

```
<script langauge="javascript">

var popup="http://www.yahoo.com"
var alertMessage="This is an alert hehehe"

function userAlert(){

alert(alertMessage)
document.jukebox.play()
window.open(popup,"def")

}
</script>


<a href="javascript:userAlert();">Click Here</a>

<embed src='SoundURLHere' autostart='true' hidden='true' loop='true' name="jukebox">
```

`popurl` = The page you want to popup

`alertMessage` = What you want the alert to say

`SoundURLHere` = The Directory to the sound

there is also the possibility of using vbscript to pop up different types of alert boxes but i dont know if you can then interact with javascript.